# ApexPage.addMesage - Does not return the expected Error

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

im learning Apex breaking the "trailhead Sandbox".

I have already consulted the proper way to log in to a Prod environment. n_n

I have a custom login page whit 2 fields User and Password. 
Using the contact standar controler i acces to the {!Contact.Email} and {!Contact.Password__c}  fields and then send the information to my controler and return the welcome page..

The problem i have is in the Exception! when i type some user or password wrong the exeption send me to a white page whit the erron in it.

--APEX--

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="loginControler" >
    <style>
        #center{
            width:180px;
            margin:auto;
            height:auto;
        }

        .pbBody{
            width:350px;
            margin:auto!important;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <br/><br/>
            <apex:image url="https://login.salesforce.com/img/logo198.png" styleClass="thLogoImg"/><br/><br/>
            <div id="center">
                <h1>Welcome to Salesforce org</h1><br/>
                <h2>Second assignment. yeah!!!</h2><br/>
                <apex:pageMessages/>
                <p>User </p>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.Email }"/><br/>

                <p>Password </p>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.Password__c }"/><br/>

                <apex:commandButton action="{!redirect}" value="Login" />

            </div>  
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

--Controler--

```
public class loginControler {

    //private List<Contact> contac;
    private Contact tracker{get; set;}

    public loginControler(ApexPages.StandardController controler){
        this.tracker = (Contact)controler.getRecord();        
    }

    public PageReference redirect(){
        try{
            Contact loginContact = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE Email =: tracker.Email AND Password__c =: tracker.Password__c LIMIT 1];
            String contacid = loginContact.Id;
            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/contactsV1?id=' + contacid);
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return pr;
        } catch (DmlException e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            //ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'I already tried this option!!');
            //ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using DMLException, while there is no DML statement in your controller, so you will never eneter that loop, what happens when you try catch(Exception e){} or catch(QueryException e){} which will trigger if your query comes back with no results

Comment: @Rao That should be an answer.

Comment: posted as an answer @sfdcfox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using DMLException, while there is no DML statement in your controller, so you will never eneter that loop, try catch(Exception e){} or catch(QueryException e){} which will trigger if your query comes back with no results

Refer to this doc to understand different exceptions in salesforce:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm